# How to benchmark and optimize a really database-intensive Rails action?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, benchmarking

There is an action in the admin section of a client's site, say Admin::Analytics (that I did not build but have to maintain) that compiles site usage analytics by performing a couple dozen, rather intensive database queries.  This functionality has always been a *bottleneck to application performance* whenever the analytics report is being compiled.  But, the bottleneck has become so bad lately that, when accessed, the site comes to a screeching halt and hangs indefinitely.  Until yesterday I never had a reason to run the "top" command on the server, but doing so I realized that Admin::Analytics#index causes *mysqld* to spin at upwards of 350+% CPU power on the quad-core, production VPS.

I have downloaded fresh copies of production data and the production log. However, when I access Admin::Analytics#index locally on my development box, while using the production data, it loads in about 10 - 12 seconds (and utilizes ~ 150+% of my dual-core CPU), which sadly is normal.  I suppose there could be a discrepancy in mysql settings that has suddenly come into play. Also, a mysqldump of the database is now 531 MB, when it was only 336 MB 28 days ago.  Anyway, I do not have root access on the VPS, so tweaking mysqld performance would be cumbersome, and I would really like to get to the exact cause of this problem.  However, the production logs don't contain info. on the queries; they merely report the length that these requests took, which average out to a few minutes apiece (although they seemed to have caused mysqld to stall for much longer than this and prompting me to request our host to reboot mysqld just to get our site back up in one instance).

I suppose I can try upping the log level in production to solicit info. on the database queries being performed by Admin::Analytics#index, but at the same time I'm afraid to replicate this behavior in production because I don't feel like calling our host up to restart mysqld again!  This action contains a single database request in its controller, and a couple dozen prepared statements embedded in its view!

How would you proceed to benchmark/diagnose and optimize/fix this action?!

(Aside: Obviously I would like to completely replace this functionality with Google Analytics or a similar solution, but I need fix this problem before proceeding.)

Comment: Which storage engine are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?  InnoDB uses a row level table lock which should allow your other queries to still work while your big queries are running. MyISAM uses a table level lock which would seems to be what is happening to your queries. You make a big query against this stats table which has inserts from every other page, while this big query is running the rest of the site will lock until the query is done if you are on MyISAM

Comment: Jonathan,

Great lead. I'm not sure, but running "show engines;" in mysql shows that MyISAM is apparently set as the "DEFAULT", while InnoDB (and 3 other engines) are apparently supported. Do you know how to determine this for sure? So far my googling is of little help...

Comment: Look at the SQL statements the app is generated.  It can be an eye-opening experience  Some of the ActiveRecord generated queries may be bad.  You may identify some things that need manual sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at this article:
http://axonflux.com/building-and-scaling-a-startup

Particularly, query_reviewer and newrelic have been a life-saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the help with this, but what turned out to be the fix for this was to implement a couple of indexes on the Analytics table to cater to the queries in this action. A simple Rails migration to add the indexes and the action now loads in less than a second both on my dev box and on prod!

Comment: I'd still recommend the article I suggested on building/scaling.  the query_reviewer plugin is great at helping you find missing indexes and implement them correctly.  I know your issue is solved but I wanted to add this in here for anyone else who may be looking for help